# Turn 3d terrain height map into just contour lines?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, objects, height-map

I want to A. Import a map from the GIS add on or B. Use a height map. I want to then display only the contour lines of the terrain as shown in this image: [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this - Start by using your height map as a basis for displacement (true displacement - using cycles - make sure to set displacement in material settings and use heavily subdivided mesh). Next, use a wave texture on the Z axis (Object coordinates) and a ColorRamp as a Mix Factor between a Transparent and an Emission Shader:

[image: Topolines]

Comment: Solved. Brilliant. Thank you.